# Promise / then returning prior to nested promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, promise

I feel like I'm missing something here, but can't quite figure it out even after reading all the other Stackoverflow questions on nested promises.

Using selenium to get a text value of an element, I use that text later, but it's null unless I manually put in a wait...

```
var someText = "";
await driver.findElement(By.css("span[title='crazyValue']")).then(function (element) {
    element.getText().then(function (text) {
        console.log("someText : " + text);
        someText = text;
    });
});

//Use someText variable immediately and it's blank...  My current solution adds an await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); to delay execution...
```

How do I make the findElement promise also wait on the inner getText promise?

Per comment, this works:

```
var someText = "";
await driver.findElement(By.css("span[title='crazyValue']")).then(function (element) {
    return element.getText().then(function (text) {
        console.log("someText : " + text);
        someText = text;
    });
});
```

But also, I think written better it should be this:

```
var someText = "";
await driver.findElement(By.css("span[title='crazyValue']")).then(function (element) {
    return element.getText();
}).then(function (text) {
        console.log("someText : " + text);
        someText = text;
});
```

Comment: 1. use `return` in front of `element.getText()`, 2. (improvement) [don't treat promises as callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to implement the improvement in my code above?  Implementing a return did work...

Comment: Don't use `.then()` nested inside another `.then()`. Promises are specifically designed to avoid that. `p.then(x => x.foo().then(y => y.bar())` is easier expressed as `p.then(x => x.foo()).then(y => y.bar())` eliminating the nested calls.

Comment: The combination of `.then` and `await` is a code-smell. If you're in an `async` function, then just use `await`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already in an `async` function, use `await` on all promises, rather than calling `.then(...)`:

```
const element = await driver.findElement(By.css("span[title='crazyValue']"));
const someText = await element.getText();
console.log("someText:", someText);
```

[async function - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)